# TreeView in tkinter app

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In my tkinter GUI application I am trying to create tree as in the picture below and display values from connected tables of my database. Right now I use TreeView widget but I dont know how to display child values(ID_B from table B). Whats wrong I did?

**ERROR:**

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ID_B FROM B_table WHERE Name_A=%s", x)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Code

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Name_A FROM A_table")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
x = []
for row in rows:
    for item in row:
        x.append(item)
        self.treeView.insert("", 1, "dir3", text=x)
        cursor.execute("SELECT ID_B FROM B_table WHERE Name_A=%s", x)
        id_rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for id_row in id_rows:
            self.treeView.insert("dir3", 1, text=id_row)
```

[image]

Comment: [ttk.Treeview](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html). The same [ttk.Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) on other page.

Comment: I saw that widget but as I understand its simple table no?!

Comment: If you use one column then you will have normal tree - with nested elements.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Can you check my post and code again pls. I have error in sql command. How to fix it?

Comment: `execute` uses `?` instead of `%s` - `execute("SELECT ID_B FROM B_table WHERE Name_A=?", x)`

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you one more question? Lets say I have third table which connected with second B_table. How to look like the second item? I mean this self.treeView.insert("dir3", 1, text=id_row). It will be parent for 3-d table and also child for 1st table. I am little bit comfused with arguments inside .insert()